# Harmonic oscillator wave equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

**Griffiths QM, problem 2.13.**

Consider the following stationary state for a particle in a harmonic oscillator potential:
$$\Psi(x,0)= \frac{1}{5} [3\psi_0(x)+4\psi_1(x)]$$
Adding the time dependence:

$$\Psi(x,t)= \frac{1}{5} [3\psi_0(x) e^{\frac{-i\hbar \omega t}{2}} +4\psi_1(x) e^{\frac{-3i\hbar \omega t}{2}}]$$
In trying to construct $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$, I used
$$a_+ \psi_n = \sqrt{n+1} \ \psi_{n+1} \qquad (1)$$ 
so the time-dependent wave function becomes:

$$\Psi(x,t)= \frac{1}{5} [3\psi_0(x) e^{\frac{-i\hbar \omega t}{2}} +4 a_+ \psi_0(x) e^{\frac{-3i\hbar \omega t}{2}}]$$
or, to simplify things,
$$\Psi(x,t)= \frac{e^{\frac{-3i\hbar \omega t}{2}}}{5} [3\psi_0(x) e^{{i\hbar \omega t}} +4 a_+ \psi_0(x) ]$$

so the complex conjugate is:
$$\Psi^*(x,t)= \frac{e^{\frac{3i\hbar \omega t}{2}}}{5} [3\psi_0(x) e^{{-i\hbar \omega t}} +4 a_- \psi_0(x) ]$$
I used the identity $a_+^\dagger = a_-$.

But, by definition of the annihilation operator, $a_- \ \psi_0=0$, so the term on the right is zeroed.

However, the solution (from Griffiths' solution manual) is different if we solved normally without using (1), and makes more sense to be honest.

I know my solution is wrong, but I don't know why. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_+ \psi_0 =\psi_1$ then the conjugate equation must evaluate to $\psi_1^*$ so that we actually have $\psi_1^* = (a_+ \psi_0)^\dagger = \psi_0^* a_+^\dagger =\psi_0^* a_-$.

When taking the hermitian conjugate yiu have to reverse the order of elements in a product. In the final two expressions the operator is u derstood to act to the left.

Comment: I see, I forgot about the reversal thing when transposing a product. Thanks!

Comment: Great! You're welcome :-)